# Prestashop Layer Cart : Add Total without tax

Tags: prestashop, layer, cart

I tried to add the following bit of code to add a line without tax in the layer cart in prestashop

```
<div class="layer_cart_row">
                <strong class="dark">
                    {l s='Total products' mod='blockcart'}
                    {if $display_tax_label}
                            {l s='(tax excl.)' mod='blockcart'}
                    {/if}
                </strong>
                <span class="ajax_block_products_total">
                    {if $cart_qties > 0}
                        {convertPrice price=$product.price_tax_exc }
                    {/if}
                </span>
            </div>
```

The line is displayed, but the price shown isn't without tax (ie: HT).

The error must be something from the convertPrice line, but I don't know what to look for...

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please, anyone with an hint?

Answer (score 0):

Change line 529 in blockcart.tpl

From:

```
{l s='Total shipping' mod='blockcart'}&nbsp;{l s='(tax excl.)' mod='blockcart'}
```

To:

```
{l s='Total shipping' mod='blockcart'}&nbsp;{l s='(tax incl.)' mod='blockcart'}
```